# Probability that the maximum element among these variables is less than the sum of these elements multiplied by a constant $c$.

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality

For $n$ exponential random variables (i.e., the probability density function is $f(t) = e^{-t}$), please calculate the probability that the maximum element among these variables is less than the sum of these elements multiplied by a constant $c$.

Namely,
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\max\{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\} < c\sum x_i\right).
$$

Many thanks!

Note that the solution via the relaxation $\mathbb{P}\left(\max\{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\} < M < c\sum x_i\right)$ is direct ($M$ is a constant), but not perfect. If there are any more beautiful solutions?

Comment: Have you tried anything? If not, you might want to read about the [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) and [order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic).

Comment: If $c\ge1$ the probability is $1$.

Comment: ... while if $c \lt \frac1n$ the probability is $0$.  You might want to experiment with $n=2,3,4$